# R.A. Lafferty? Story about ship going back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This question ([Sci fi novel about a modern warship that goes back in time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185576/sci-fi-novel-about-a-modern-warship-that-goes-back-in-time)) reminded me of a story, that I think was by R.A. Lafferty. It was a novel or long story that I probably read in the 1960s

The plot was about a boat or ship, possibly a sailboat, that travels back in time to the Mediterranean in Roman times.  I believe that it was the reign of Augustus, the first emperor, about 27 BC to AD 14, and that the Mediterranean was not as peaceful as one might suppose.

The list of [R.A. Lafferty stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?36) doesn't have any titles that sound like they could be about nautical time travel to ancient Rome though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be "The ship that sailed the time stream" (1965) by G C Edmonson

> The special research vessel Alice was the oddest ship that ever flew the ensign of the United States Navy; small, wooden-hulled and sail-powered, she would have been less out of place in the Navy of a hundred years ago — if it weren’t for the electrician’s nightmare of a christmas tree hanging from her main boom.
>   The purpose of the “christmas tree” was to detect enemy submarines. It wasn’t very good at that, but when lightning struck it proved itself highly efficient at… something else. For when the smoke cleared, there off the port bow was a long-ship. Full of Vikings. Throwing things.
>   The Alice had become… The Ship That Sailed The Time Stream.

Comment: Having looked at the cover here http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47126  and read a detailed review here, https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/peace-time-milsf  I am convinced you are right.  Answer accepted.